# equivalent definitions of ideals in non commutative, non associative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

**Definition:** An ideal $P$ of $L$ is called *prime* if $[H, K] \subseteq P$ with $H, K$ ideals of $L$ implies $H \subseteq P$ or $K \subseteq P$

**THEOREM:** Let $P$ be an ideal of $L .$ Then the following conditions are equivalent:

i) $P$ is prime.

ii) If $[a, H] \subseteq P$ for $a \in L$ and an ideal $H$ of $L,$ then either $a \in P$ or $H \subseteq P$

iii) If $\left[a,<b^{L}>\right] \subseteq P$ for $a, b \in L,$ then either $a \in P$ or $b \in P$

iv)   If $\left[<a^{L}>,<b^{L}>\right] \subseteq P$ for $a, b \in L,$ then either $a \in P$ or $b \in P$

Why the definition can not be: An ideal $P$ of $L$ is called *prime* if $[x, y] \in P$ with $x, y$ elements of $L$ implies $x \in P$ or $y \in P$

If anyone say that $[x,x]=0 \in P$ and $x \notin P$ so there is no prime ideals..
I think we can exclude this case and say :An ideal $P$ of $L$ is called *prime* if $0\neq [x, y]  \in P$ with $x, y$ elements of $L$ implies $x \in P$ or $y \in P$

Any participation would be appreciated.

Comment: With that proposed new definition, $(0)$ would be a prime ideal in any algebra. That seems off.

Comment: How $(0)$ would be a prime ideal?? Mr.@TorstenSchoeneberg

Comment: Because for $P:=\{0\}$, if $x,y\in L$ with $0 \neq [x,y] \in P$, then ... whatever, as there are no such $x,y$. (Vacuous truth.)

Comment: I understand your helpful comments Mr.@TorstenSchoeneberg: i.e The zero ideal  would be a prime ideal in any algebra.
But I need your opinion if we exclude the zero ideal from the definition as like as all the authors exclude the ring itself in the definition of prime ideal .
i.e An ideal P of a commutative ring R is prime if it has the following two properties:
If a and b are two elements of R such that their product ab is an element of P, then a is in P or b is in P, and
P is not the whole ring R.

Comment: But then please clarify: With your proposed definition, how can we tell in a given algebra $L$ whether the zero ideal is prime or not? Do we just say, by definition, it never is? Feels strange too, but possible of course, and maybe (for Lie algebras at least) a little less strange than it always being prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggested definition 1:** An ideal P of L is called prime if [x,y]∈P with x,y elements of L implies x∈P or y∈P
comment on it form Mr.@TorstenSchoeneberg: since [x,x]=0∈P and x∉P so there is no prime ideals.

**Suggested definition 2**An ideal P of L is called prime if [x,y]∈P with x,y elements of L implies x∈P or y∈P
comment on it form Mr.@TorstenSchoeneberg: With that proposed new definition, (0) would be a prime ideal in any algebra. 
Because for P:={0}, if x,y∈L with 0≠[x,y]∈P, then ... whatever, as there are no such x,y. 
Thanks To Mr.@TorstenSchoeneberg